# Sending e-mail from generic accounts Exchange 2007

Tags: email, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

I have generic email accounts, which I want several AD users to monitor, such as enquiries@xyz.com and support@xyz.com. They need to be able to use the from field or global address list within their Outlook 2003/2007 to select these generic accounts when sending e-mail and also be able to add the relevant mailbox to view incoming e-mails. How can this be achieved in a windows 2008 Server/domain & Exchange 2007 environment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simple answer is [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA100750811033.aspx) or are you looking for something else?

and if you want to do this programatically, you can call the exchange web services (EWS) as detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb856527(v=EXCHG.140).aspx).